# Creating a heap in C with arbitrary node types. How to free it?

Tags: c, data-structures, heap-memory, free

Asking for a sanity check on this design choice.

I'm writing a heap sort in C by creating a heap data structure that can accept node types of string or numerical. (I'm creating my own private heap that I can sort)

The nodes in the heap are void*, which are dereferenced to perform the comparison operations. The Heap struct stores the sizeof each node in Heap.nodesize, or -1 if the node is a string.

When a node is inserted, memory is allocated for the void*. If the Heap.nodesize is -1, strlen(val) is passed to malloc, otherwise Heap.nodesize is passed to malloc.

When performing comparisons, if Heap.nodesize is -1 strcmp is used, otherwise boolean operators are used for the numerical.

When the heap is freed, I plan to loop through and free each void*. At this point will free know how many bytes to free for each node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to know the originally `malloc`ed size. You just pass the pointer that `malloc()` returned to `free()`.

```
ssize_t size = 400;
void* p = malloc(size);
// Do whatever with p
free(p);
```

Comment: right, I'm reading my question, and realizing that free must know the number of bytes that I passed to malloc originally.

Comment: You really don't care; those are implementation details of the `libc` in use.  Just remember, if you get a pointer from `malloc()`, you must pass the same pointer value back to `free()` exactly once.

Comment: @OregonTrail: It usually doesn't know how many bytes you passed to `malloc`, but it does know whatever it needs to know. (Typically the number of bytes actually allocated, but it varies from implementation to implementation.)

Comment: @David Yes. This implies that `malloc` can (and probably does) actually return a larger buffer than you requested (some multiple of its internal unit size).

Answer (score 0):

`free` don't need to  know the number of bytes,just use it as 'Jonathon Reinhart' said.There is a simple implementation of `malloc` and `free` in chapter 8 in [TCPL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628).Just read it,and you will know how `free` works without knowing the size of you dynamic allocated memory.Hope it works!